# alternative to sample function with varying sampling range

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

Is there an alternative to the *sample function* in Openmodelica, which accepts arguments which are not of `type parameter`? That is, the alternative should permit the sampling of a variable range of values during a simulation.

The end goal is to create a class with which I can measure the RMS value of a real signal during a simulation. The RMS value is used as a control variable. The real signal has a continuously changing frequency so in order to have better measurements, I want to either be able to varry the sampling range continuously during simulation or discretely in some sections/periods of the oscillation.

Is it also possible to have a "running RMS" function so that the output is continuous?

In short, I would like to calculate the RMS value over a variable sampling range and the sample should only have one new term or value per iteration and not a completely new set of values.

Comment: I guess you could use something like: http://doc.modelica.org/om/Modelica.Blocks.Discrete.TriggeredSampler.html
and you base the trigger input on some expression based on time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some possible solutions (you probably should check my math and just use them for inspiration; also check the RootMeanSquare block in the standard library which for some reason samples the Mean block):

Running RMS from beginning of time (no frequency).

```
model RMS
  Real signal = sin(time);
  Real rms = if time < 1e-10 then signal else sqrt(i_sq / time /* Assume start-time is 0; can also integrate the denominator using der(denom)=1 for a portable solution. Remember to guard the first period of time against division by zero */);
  Real i_sq(start=0, fixed=true) "Integrated square of the signal";
equation
  der(i_sq) = signal^2;
end RMS;
```

With a fixed window, f:

```
model RMS
  constant Real f = 2*2*asin(1.0);
  Real signal = sin(time);
  Real rms = if time < f then (if time < 1e-10 then signal else sqrt(i_sq / time)) else sqrt(i_sq_f / f);
  Real i_sq(start=0, fixed=true);
  Real i_sq_f = i_sq - delay(i_sq, f);
equation
  der(i_sq) = signal^2;
end RMS;
```

With a variable window, f (limited by f_max):

```
model RMS
  constant Real f_max = 2*2*asin(1.0);
  constant Real f = 1+abs(2*asin(time));
  Real signal = sin(time);
  Real rms = if time < f then (if time < 1e-10 then signal else sqrt(i_sq / time)) else sqrt(i_sq_f / f);
  Real i_sq(start=0, fixed=true);
  Real i_sq_f = i_sq - delay(i_sq, f, f_max);
equation
  der(i_sq) = signal^2;
end RMS;
```

Variable time for sampling in synchronous Modelica: https://trac.modelica.org/Modelica/ticket/2022

Variable time for sampling in older Modelica:

```
when time>=nextEvent then
  doSampleStuff(...);
  nextEvent = calculateNextSampleTime(...);
end when;
```

Comment: this suits my need!