# Variable sampling frequency in OpenModelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am referring to this post:

[alternative to sample function with varying sampling range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145868/alternative-to-sample-function-with-varying-sampling-range)

I want to measure an RMS value (or a mean value) with a variable sampling frequency, which i can feed in as an input signal.

The suggested way which nearly suits my need is the following:

```
model RMS
  constant Real f_max = 2*2*asin(1.0);
  constant Real f = 1+abs(2*asin(time));
  Real signal = sin(time);
  Real rms = if time < f then (if time < 1e-10 then signal else sqrt(i_sq / time)) else sqrt(i_sq_f / f);
  Real i_sq(start=0, fixed=true);
  Real i_sq_f = i_sq - delay(i_sq, f, f_max);
equation
  der(i_sq) = signal^2;
end RMS;
```

This one throws the error: Component f of variability CONST has binding 1.0 + abs(2.0 * asin(time)) of higher variability VAR.

Is there a way to solve this problem and feed in the frequency as a real input value?

Answer (score 3):

The expression for `f` is time-varying but `f` is declared as `constant`.

Simply replace `constant Real f = ...` with `input Real f = ...`. Then you can specify `f` from the "outside" of the model if you like.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with the code is, that `time` is a variable, meaning it changes its value over time. This corresponds to a continuous time expression in the [Modelica Language Specification](https://modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec34.pdf) (see Chapter 3.8). A variable can only be assigned to variable with equal or higher variability. Therefore it is not possible to assign something computed from `time` to constant, as the result will not be constant. Thus, removing the `constant` in the definition of `f` will solve the issue.

Replacing `constant` with `input` in the definition of `f` will make the tool expect `f` to be provided from the outside. Alternatively you can use `Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput`.

Also `f_max` sounds rather like a `parameter` than a `constant`...

Besides that, if time gets greater than `1`, there will be an issue with ´asin(time)´. But that is a different story...

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, some problems occurred in he example above. One with the constant Real f, one with the constant real f_max, and on positions where the time difference was needed, the frequency was used instead.

Following is a working block

```
model RMS
  constant Real f_max = 10000;
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput f annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {0, 106}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = -90), iconTransformation(origin = {0, 106}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = -90))); 
 Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput signal annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-108, 0}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-108, 0}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  Real dt = 1/f;
  Real rms = if time < dt then (if time < 1e-10 then signal else sqrt(i_sq / time)) else sqrt(i_sq_f / dt);
  Real i_sq(start=0, fixed=true);  
  Real testi = delay(i_sq, dt, f_max);
  Real i_sq_f = i_sq - delay(i_sq, dt, f_max);
Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput y annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {110, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {110, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  der(i_sq) = signal^2;
  y = rms;
end RMS;
```

Edit: Your simulation step size must be greater than the time in the first if-condition. Otherwise, this programm still might throw errors (division by 0)